# Displaceability questions of fibers on integrable hamiltonian systems

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Alot is known about the (non)-displaceability of the fibers of a toric symplectic manifold. For example there is Mcduff's method of probes to prove displaceability results using the moment polytope, work on Lagrangian Floer theory to prove non-displaceability questions, etc...

I was wondering if anything is known for the case where we have a torus action $\mathbb{T}^k$ with $k<n$, where $n$ is such that the dimension of the symplectic manifold $M$ is $\dim M=2n$.

Furthermore, what about a more general integrable hamiltonian system? The only result I know is using symplectic quasi-states, which says that under certain tecnhical conditions on the symplectic manifold, one can use partial symplectic quasi-states to prove that at least one non-displaceable fiber exists.

Does anyone know of any references regarding these generalizations, to try and study (non)-displaceable fibers in a more general setting.
Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.